# How long has the singular noun 'archive', as opposed to 'archives', been in current use?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

My question arises through the fact that, when Michel Foucault introduced 'archive' as a singular noun in his 1969 Archaeology of Knowledge, he was more or less inventing a new word. 'Archif' and 'archive' (both n. m.) were used in Old French only, and Foucault's noun is a neologism, rather than a retrologism, in that's a feminine noun. Can anyone tell me what the singular/plural situation for English 'archive(s)' was around that time? PS In France today, there are still some major dictionaries that don't recognise the singular form.

Comment: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=archive_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carchive_NOUN%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Carchive_NOUN%3B%2Cc1) *suggests* that there was usage of the singular before 1969, but you'd have to explore the individual occurrences as the ngrams can be misleading...

Comment: [1953 reference](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=hTUhAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22archive+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCgJqXyabfAhWQaCsKHRtQBAM4FBDoAQhQMAc#v=onepage&q=%22archive%20of%22&f=false) to *Schott's archive of recorder consorts*

Comment: Following up from Chappo, the earliest Ngram is at **1725**. (don't know where it got that)

Comment: Are you kidding, or what?

If you think anyone introduced 'archive' as a singular noun in 1969, how can you demonstrate that? How can you show it was "introduced"? 

To the extent 'Archif' and 'archive' were used anywhere, Foucault's noun is not a neologism, is it?

When in France, there are still any dictionaries which don't recognise the singular form how, exactly, do their comments translate to English